How to programmatically verify "Podpis Zaufany" (XAdES Format) from Polish Administration?
Does anyone have a working example to share? Could be in any programming language.
Let me mention that I tried xml-crypto in node.js but I failed due to: "Error: canonicalization algorithm 'http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116' is not supported".
Thank you!
